How do I delete or purge localstack completely from my machine? (MAC OS 14.3.1 (23D60))
I've had issues with localstack, so I wanted to delete it and reinstall a new. I tried multiple commands to remove it which included pip uninstall localstack-cli, pip3 unistall localstack-cli and even brew unistall localstack-cli. But once I close terminal, open a new instance and run localstack --version I get a version number 0.13.0.11
Any ideas on how to purge it from my machine would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

So I found that when I ran which localstack that it was hiding in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/localstack. So once I deleted all remnant of Python it is now completely removed.
